# Dataset Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset with a single datatable that goes as follows:

```
...
<description>"abcd"</description>
<date>"1/1/2001"</date>
... 
<description>"1234"</description>
<date>"1/1/2001"</date>
...
<description>"abcd"</description>
<date>"1/1/2001"</date>
...
```

I want to construct a new dataset, that contains the same values, rows and columns but only where the description is "abcd", per se.

i.e, for the example values I gave, I'd like to get:

```
...
<description>"abcd"</description>
<date>"1/1/2001"</date>
... 
<description>"abcd"</description>
<date>"1/1/2001"</date>
...
```

I've seen the [`DataTable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but I'm not sure if it's a good way or can work at all for what I'm trying to do.

What's the best practice to do such a thing?

Comment: Select is a method of the DataTable class not of the DataSet. Did you try to use it and have something to show?

Comment: @Steve Yes, but nothing meaningful. I've tried to use Select on the first table, and got gibberish. I'm not even sure that's a good way to do what I'm trying to do - there might be some clone method which's better.

Comment: If you have already that table in memory then Select is a viable method to reach your goal. However a DataSet could have more than one table and you should know which table contains your values and apply Select and then CopyToDataTable to extract the rows. By the way, adding a bit of code also if not working is always better because it adds context to your question

Comment: @Steve I didnt know of the CopyToDataTable method. That solved everything for me. If you'll write that as an answer, I'll accept it. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select method extracts an array of DataRow from the DataTable to which it is applied.

```
DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select("description = 'abcd'");
```

Having the rows array declared you could check if there is something returned by the `Select` method and convert the array to a DataTable using the IEnumerable extension called [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DataTable foundData = null;
if(rows != null)
    foundData = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Notice that the DataSet is not involved in this process but it is just the container of your original table and the new table returned by CopyToDataTable is not included in the Tables collection of the DataSet.